# How to install elasticsearch in custom path?

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, sles

I need to install Elasticsearch to path `/opt/elasticsearch/` with all information in this path.
I mean, I need config path put in opt too.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/settings.html it says here I can set `ES_PATH_CONF` and `ES_HOME` env vars to change installation and config paths, but it doesn't work.

`rpm --install elasticsearch-7.15.0-x86_64.rpm --prefix=/opt/elasticsearch/` it's not what I need and doesn't change config path.

It makes home directory in /opt/elasticsearch, and I get next structure and paths doesn't change. It still needs execution bins in /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/

```
el6:~ # tree /opt/elasticsearch/ -d -L 3
/opt/elasticsearch/
├── lib
│   ├── sysctl.d
│   ├── systemd
│   │   └── system
│   └── tmpfiles.d
└── share
    └── elasticsearch
        ├── bin
        ├── jdk
        ├── lib
        ├── modules
        └── plugins
```

but i need

```
el5:~ # tree /opt/elasticsearch/ -d -L 1
/opt/elasticsearch/
├── bin
├── config
├── data
├── jdk
├── lib
├── logs
├── modules
└── plugins
```

with manually installation
`mkdir /opt/elasticsearch/ && tar -xzf elasticsearch-7.15.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz -C /opt/elasticsearch/ --strip-components 1`
I have needed me structure. I made systemd service

```
    [Unit]
    Description=Elasticsearch
    Documentation=https://www.elastic.co
    Wants=network-online.target
    After=network-online.target
    
    [Service]
    Type=notify
    RuntimeDirectory=elasticsearch
    PrivateTmp=true
    Environment=ES_HOME=/opt/elasticsearch
    Environment=ES_PATH_CONF=/opt/elasticsearch/config
    Environment=PID_DIR=/var/run/elasticsearch
    Environment=ES_SD_NOTIFY=true
    EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch
    
    WorkingDirectory=/opt/elasticsearch
    
    User=elasticsearch
    Group=elasticsearch
    
    ExecStart=/opt/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet
    
    # StandardOutput is configured to redirect to journalctl since
    # some error messages may be logged in standard output before
    # elasticsearch logging system is initialized. Elasticsearch
    # stores its logs in /var/log/elasticsearch and does not use
    # journalctl by default. If you also want to enable journalctl
    # logging, you can simply remove the "quiet" option from ExecStart.
    StandardOutput=journal
    StandardError=inherit
    
    # Specifies the maximum file descriptor number that can be opened by this process
    LimitNOFILE=65535
    
    # Specifies the maximum number of processes
    # Specifies the maximum number of processes
    LimitNPROC=4096
    
    # Specifies the maximum size of virtual memory
    LimitAS=infinity
    
    # Specifies the maximum file size
    LimitFSIZE=infinity
    
    # Disable timeout logic and wait until process is stopped
    TimeoutStopSec=0
    
    # SIGTERM signal is used to stop the Java process
    KillSignal=SIGTERM
    
    # Send the signal only to the JVM rather than its control group
    KillMode=process
    
    # Java process is never killed
    SendSIGKILL=no
    
    # When a JVM receives a SIGTERM signal it exits with code 143
    SuccessExitStatus=143
    
    # Allow a slow startup before the systemd notifier module kicks in to extend the timeout
    TimeoutStartSec=5000
    
    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But it doesn't start, doesn't crash, and doesn't write any logs in journalctl.

How can I install elasticsearch in opt with configs in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install elasticsearch to `/opt/elasticsearch` using your `rpm`command, then move the config files from their default location to your location of choice, and finally change the `ES_PATH_CONF`and `ES_HOME` env vars to their respective new path.

When using the "manual" installation method (by downloading the .tar.gz) you have the freedom to put the files where you want. `wget` returns 404 because the file/URL does not exist. `wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.15.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz` should be the correct one. (you're missing `-linux`)

Comment: Thanks! There is a way to autoconfigure systemd launch with "manual" installation, or I must do it by myself?

Answer (score 1):

the only way to do that is to download the tar.gz into your directory and then manually add all the environment variables, and build and manage your own init script